# How to join multiple tables into one in sql group by gid,uid?

Tags: sql

This is a problem encountered in the project. Please look at my picture description.

I need to aggregate multiple tables into one. The uid and gid are fixed, and other xxx_count is different.

Can use mysql or oracle sql to do it.

[image]

Comment: MySQL <> Oracle. Please retag the question with actual RDBMS you are using.

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Which database ?

Comment: Oracle or Sybase IQ are most likely to be used, but it's only at the solution stage, and it's not yet decided which database to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need a `Full Outer Join` with `Coalesce()`. Following query should work on major RDBMS (except MySQL):

```
SELECT 
  a.uid,
  a.gid, 
  COALESCE(a.file_count, 0) AS file_count, 
  COALESCE(b.reply_count, 0) AS reply_count, 
  COALESCE(c.ask_count, 0) AS ask_count 
FROM 
 a 
FULL OUTER JOIN b ON a.uid = b.uid AND a.gid = b.gid 
FULL OUTER JOIN c ON a.uid = c.uid AND a.gid = c.gid
```

Comment: Of course, you could hack something in MySQL that simulates a `FULL OUTER JOIN`. But if OP can do it in Oracle, then it's a moot point.

Comment: @Zack yes in the process of adding mysql solution.

Comment: help much! And i think I will try to run it in oracle or sybase iq which I am new for them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union all` and `group by`:

```
select uid, gid, sum(file_count), sum(reply_count), sum(ask_count)
from ((select uid, gid, file_count, 0 as reply_count, 0 as ask_count from a
      ) union all
      (select uid, gid, 0 as file_count, reply_count, 0 as ask_count from b
      ) union all
      (select uid, gid, 0 as file_count, 0 as reply_count, ask_count from c
      )
     ) abc
group by uid, gid;
```

If find that with multiple tables, this approach is simpler than `full join` -- having to deal with all the `NULL` values that `full join`s create is cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

Using nvl function from Oracle, maybe this will help you:

```
select a.uid, a.gid, nvl(a.file_count,0) , nvl(b.reply_count, 0), nvl(c.ask_count,0)
from a
left join b on a.uid = b.uid and a.gid = b.gid
left join c on a.uid = c.uid and a.gid = c.gid
```

Comment: OP wants records that exist in `B` or `C` but not in `A`, which would not be returned with your `LEFT JOIN`.